# How do I make Django unit tests check M2M DB constraints?

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have this model definition:

```
class Foo(Model):
   ...

class Bar(Model):
   some_m2m_field = ManyToManyField(Foo)
```

and this code:

```
bar = Bar.objects.create()
bar.some_m2m_field.set(an_id_array_with_some_invalid_pks)
```

When I run that normally, the last line will, as it should, throw an `IntegrityError`.  However, if I run the same code from a `django.test.TestCase`, the last line will NOT throw an error.  It instead will wait until the `_post_teardown()` phase of the test to throw the `IntegrityError`.

Here's a small project that demonstrates the issue: https://github.com/t-evans/m2mtest

How do I fix that?  I suppose that's configurable, but I haven't been able to find it...

**Follow-up question:**

Ultimately, I need to handle the case when there are bad IDs being passed to the `m2m_field.set()` method (and I need unit tests that verify that bad IDs are being handled correctly, which is why the delayed `IntegrityError` in the unit test won't work).

I know I can find the bad IDs by looping over the array and hitting the DB one for each ID.  Is there a more efficient way to find the bad IDs or (better) simply tell the `set()` method to ignore/drop the bad IDs?

Comment: What database are you using? Postgres would cause the `set` method to error immediately upon execution, not in the tear down. Also, fake code explaining the issue isn't nearly as helpful as the actual code that errors. If it's complex, rework it until it's simple and still causing the error and share that with us.

Comment: Unfortunately the `IntegrityError` will only return one invalid id. You could try ... except, remove the id in the except and retry (iterate until it passes), removing the bad ids one by one until no exception is thrown.

Comment: @schillingt - I'm using Postgres, but it's still not erring immediately...  I'll see if I can set up a small/test django app that duplicates the issue.

Comment: Are you using a `TransactionTestCase` or a `TestCase`?

Comment: @dirkgroten - I'm using a `django.test.TestCase`, which extends `TransactionTestCase`.

Comment: `TestCase` wraps tests in additional `atomic()` blocks, compared to `TransactionTestCase`, so to test specific database transaction behaviour, you should use `TransactionTestCase`. But I still wouldn't expect the `IntegrityError` to only be thrown `post_teardown()`. To test, try using a `with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):` wrapper.

Comment: @dirkgroten - Using a `TransactionTestCase` instead of `TestCase` resolves the issue.  Can you post that as an answer rather than a comment so I can mark that as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestCase` wraps tests in additional `atomic()` blocks, compared to `TransactionTestCase`, so to test specific database transaction behaviour, you should use `TransactionTestCase`.

I believe an `IntegrityError` is thrown only when the transaction is committed, as that's the moment the db would find out about missing `id`s.

In general if you want to test for db exceptions raised during a test, you should use a `TransactionTestCase` and test your code using:

```
with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
     # do something that gets committed to db
```

Answer (score 1):

See the answer from @dirkgroten for how to fix the unit test issue.

As for the followup question on how to more-efficiently eliminate the bad IDs, one way is as follows:

```
good_ids = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=an_id_array_with_some_invalid_ids).values_list('id', flat=True)
```